# Conditional tags not working

Tags: conditional-tags

I'd like to display some CSS only for [this page](http://www.piedmontpool.com/events).

In the theme's header.php, I have tried both:

```
<?php if(is_page('events')) { ?>
<style>
  #main {
    background-image: none;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

and

```
<?php if(is_page(43)) { ?>
<style>
  #main {
    background-image: none;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

but these have not succeeded.

I am assuming the slug is "events", and I know the page ID is 43.

Why are these both failing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the WP_Query for this URL? (what is query variables that passed to wp_query on this page - you can get this info from *debug bar* plugin - WP Query tab)...

Comment: are you sure you are targeting the right page? page 43 for instance has the slug 'calendar-of-events'; 'events' seems to be an archive. consider to use the specific `body_class()` output to style the background.

Comment: @Michael I changed the slug to 'calendar-of-events' and the problem remained.  Can I use body_class() to style a tag which is not the body tag?

Comment: Steve, please read about "Css Selectors". This is off topic.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the classes being output by `body_class()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of echoing your styles anywhere, you can hook your code at wp_head to add it in head or wp_footer to add it in your footer, see if it works for you,

```
function my_custom_style(){
  global $post;
  if ( !empty ( $post->post_name ) && $post->post_name == 'events' ){ ?>
      <style type="text/css"> 
        #main { background-image: none; }
      </style>
  }

}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_style' );
```

or

```
add_action ( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_style' );
```

I just saw your page, if you can modify your style then add this to it:

```
 .events-gridview.events-archive #main {
      background: none;
  }
```

if you can't then use the

```
  function my_custom_style(){ ?>
     <style type="text/css"> 
        .events-gridview.events-archive #main {
           background: none;
        }
      </style> <?php
  }

}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_style' );
```

It would work without conflict.

Comment: Tried this and the code is not being injected.  I don't think we're getting the right post_name.  The page is generated by a plugin - it is not a Wordpress post or page.

Comment: is this code hosted somewhere, so that I can take a look

Comment: [This is functions.php](http://pastebin.com/077qCZQX)

Comment: The CSS `.events-gridview.events-archive #main {background: none;}` worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Ha, you remember to reply finally, gr8 to know that it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

To get `post id` `outside` the `loop` use below code:

```
<?php 
global $post; 
$id_of_page_or_post=$post->ID;
if($id_of_page_or_post==43){
//do your stuff
} 
?>
```

Comment: Didn't work either unfortunately @deepa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use. `get_the_ID()` function to getting the id of the page or the post. then write a

```
$id_of_page_or_post = get_the_ID();
if($id_of_page_or_post==43){
// do something
}
```

for more reference you can look to the [Wordpress Codex of get_the_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.  The URL in question is generated by The Events Calendar plugin.  When I am logged in, I do not see 'edit page' in the admin bar for this URL.

Comment: Please elaborate your question so I could explain that. I'm not getting what you mean ?
You can debug that by using `echo` or `print` command

Comment: The [webpage](http://www.piedmontpool.com/events) is not a Wordpress post or page.  It is generated by a plugin.